# Google Drive API suddenly does not authenticate - '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'

Tags: google-drive-api

hoping for some support on our Google Drive API. We have a script that creates Google Drive folders when new clients are added. This script worked great for over 6 months, and suddenly broke. The error we get is:

```
Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'
```

I'd like to stress that nothing in our code changed. The tokens simply stopped authenticating for all users.

We are going mad trying to figure out why this would "randomly" happen one day. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  try {
            require '/var/www/html/s2/googledrive/vendor/autoload.php';

            define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Drive API Quickstart');
            define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/dirrec.json');
            define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', '/var/www/html/client_secret.json');
            define('SCOPES', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

            $client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
            $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
            $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
            $client->setAccessType('offline');

            // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.

            require_once('include/upload_file.php');

            $file = new UploadFile();

            //get the file location
            $file->temp_file_location = 'custom/modules/Accounts/dirrec.json';
            $accessToken = $file->get_file_contents();
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
            $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

            // Refresh the token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                file_put_contents('custom/modules/Accounts/dirrec.json', $client->getAccessToken());
            }
```

Comment: you are not handling the revoked token case. see it in oauth2 samples. either user revoked or changed password.

Comment: If that is the case... "token revoked" How do I fix it? I tried creating new credentials (clientID, secret) that did nothing. This occurs with all of our users not just one.

Comment: why would creating new client ids work? it will break even more. security is important, dont just try things, study the oauth2 flow, is really not hard.

Comment: The above code worked for 6 months, then one day stopped. So the flow was never a problem. That is why I'm at a loss here.

Comment: it worked because you never tested the branch that deals with revoked tokens. for example you should email the user to inform they need to click a link to reauthorize.

Comment: The application is internal so we have admin access to the account which owns the credentials and the user accounts. We built token refresh into the script, but I do not know how to ask for a new token altogether if the old one is "revoked" and refresh therefore fails.